# Android EditText - Consume event of a specific key press

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-event

I have a class `MyEditText` that extends `EditText`.
When receiving a specific keycode from an InputMethodService, say 35 which is equivilant of `'#'`, I want to perform an action on
my EditText instead of appending it to the text.

Solutions that did not work:

1. Setting an `onEditorActionListener` does not help since `onEditAction()` is called only for a specific set of codes such as `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`, and I need to detect the event of receiving a code out of that set.
2. Setting an onKeyListener. This also did not work but I don't know the reason and I am not even sure this listener is meant for this purpose. This is the code I tried and it doesn't log anything when typing:

   ```
   edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           Log.d("EDITOR_TAG", "onKey()");
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

   **Edit:** after further testing the `onKey()` also gets called for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` but not other key codes. Just like `onEditorAction()`.
3. A workaround that might work but I prefer to avoid: implementing `beforeTextChanged()`, `onTextChanged()` and `afterTextChanged()` of the `TextWatcher` interface.
   The reason I want to avoid this is that it will interfere with a history mechanism implemented in those methods (for undo/redo).
   I want to consume the event of receiving a key code 35 before it even changes the text.

Comment: what do you mean by *receiving a key code 35 before it even changes the text*, How can you get the text before it changes ? Does it mean same as  `beforeTextChanged()` of TextWatcher ?

Comment: These 3 methods of `TextWatcher` are should only be called if the text changes. If you catch the event, in `onEditorAction()` for example, and return true which means you're done handling the event, these methods will not be called. Unfortunately it works only for a specific set of characters as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This wrapper class, hope it will solve your problem :

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    if (lengthBefore < lengthAfter) {
        char c = text.charAt(start + lengthAfter - 1);
        if (c == '#') {
            char[] newChars = new char[text.length() - 1];
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                if (i != (start + lengthAfter - 1))
                    newChars[j++] = text.charAt(i);
            }
            setText(new String(newChars));
        }
    }
}
```

}

As per my rnd I didn't find any direct method of doing this without TextWatcher. However I found a workaround, It is working fine but need little modification as per your custom requirements.

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: As I already stated this solution did not work for me. I added the actual code now, maybe you will find something wrong in it.

Comment: I added the results of this attempt to the question. Did you test it yourself?

Comment: @tba try the updated code, It should work perfect :)

Comment: Looks interesting. I didn't think of implementing an inner class. I'll try it and report the results soon.

Comment: Sure, looking for positive answer :)

Comment: Weirdly, this also only only catches the event with `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`. I took exactly your code and changed the `isEscapeKey()` to always return true and added logging in `sendKeyEvent()`. When I pressed enter on the keyboard it logged an event with keycode 66. Any other keyboard presses did not log anything.

Comment: Okay, Let me check!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114652/discussion-between-neo-and-tba).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same challenge and came up with a solution.
Just copy paste the following class to your project:

**OnTextChangedListener.class**

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class OnTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher {

    private static final String TAG = OnTextChangedListener.class.getSimpleName();

    private boolean isManualChange = false;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private char[] consumeChars;

    public OnTextChangedListener(char[] consumeChars, EditText editText){
        mEditText = editText;
        if(consumeChars == null){
            this.consumeChars = new char[0];
        } else{
            this.consumeChars = consumeChars;
        }
    }

    public OnTextChangedListener(){
        this.consumeChars = new char[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
        String newString = charSequence.toString();
        if(containsConsumeChar(newString)){
            newString = removeConsumeChars(newString);
            int cursorPos = mEditText.getSelectionStart(); // or getSelectionEnd() doesn't matter
            isManualChange = true;
            mEditText.setText(newString);
            int maxPos = newString.length();
            mEditText.setSelection(cursorPos > maxPos ? maxPos : cursorPos);
        } else if(before != count && !isManualChange){
            Log.d(TAG, "Text (actually) changed!");
            String text = charSequence.toString();

            // calls your own implementation if you have one
            onTextActuallyChanged(text, start, before, count);
        } else{
            Log.d(TAG, "consumed manual change");
            isManualChange = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }

    public void onTextActuallyChanged(String newText, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthNow){

    }

    public void onCharacterConsumed(char consumed){

    }

    private boolean containsConsumeChar(String text){
        for(char c : consumeChars){
            if(text.contains(""+c)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private String removeConsumeChars(String text){
        for(char c : consumeChars){
            if(text.contains(""+c)){
                Log.d(TAG, "consumed all '" + c + "'s");
                text = text.replaceAll(""+c, "");

                // calls your own implementation if you have one
                onCharacterConsumed(c);
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
OnTextChangedListener consumeThis = new OnTextChangedListener(new char[]{'#'}, myEditText);
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(consumeThis);
```

or

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new OnTextChangedListener(new  char['#'], myEditText){
    @Override
    public void onCharacterConsumed(char consumed) {
        // TODO: implement your magic here
    }
});
```